# R equivalent for postgres nextval()

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny

I am building an app in R Shiny.
After clicking on "enter data" a UI is displayed where the user enters the data.
When clicking on "submit" the entered data is stored in a PostgreSQL database.
Right now I am storing the database via the `dbGetQuery()` command as a reactive datatable locally. Then I simply increment the ID, the primary key, by 1 and add the data to my reactive Datatable. Then I use `dbWriteTable()` to insert it into Postgres.

This procedure leads to primary key issues when multiple users want to enter data at the same time.
Is there a method that the session somehow "secures" the next ID for the user when the user clicks on "enter data" such that another user gets the next ID? This would resolve the primary key problems.

In Postgres, I read about the `setval()` or `nextval()` command, but I am looking for something similar in R Shiny.

Comment: I think you probably want to take a look at the [pool](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html) package for better db connection management.

Comment: AFAIK you don't need to update the PK-column yourself - just insert all the other columns and postgres will take care about providing that update with a new key (also for concurrent updates). See the example [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update/) or [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-insert/). PS: run your insert statement via `dbExecute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can make use of the id sequences of postgres by using `dbGetQuery(con, "select nextval(table)")$nextval`.